# Integrating terracotta with grails

Tags: grails, terracotta

Created empty grails project

`grails create-app foo`

Modified `BuildConfig.groovy`, uncommented

```
inherits("global") {  
  // uncomment to disable ehcache                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  excludes 'ehcache'                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

So now `ehcache` is excluded.

Copied these 5 jars from `terracotta` installation to `foo/lib` directory:

```
ehcache-core-ee-2.6.2.jar
ehcache-terracotta-ee-2.6.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar
terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-ee-5.2.0.jar
```

Created `ehcache.xml` in `grails-app/conf/` directory:

```
<ehcache>

  <terracottaConfig url="vm4:9510"/>

   <defaultCache
       maxElementsInMemory="50"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="20"
       timeToLiveSeconds="20"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       diskPersistent="false"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">

    <terracotta clustered="true" valueMode="serialization"/>
  </defaultCache>

</ehcache>
```

Running project through `grails run-app` and getting this exception:

```
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: 
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Could not create ClusteredInstanceFactory due to missing class. Please verify that terracotta-toolkit is in your classpath.
```

Comment: What version of grails are you using ?

Comment: 2.1.1 actually the problem has been solved already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the jars from `foo/lib` directory, and insert some dependencies into BuildConfig.groovy:

```
    repositories {
        .....
        mavenRepo "http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases"
    }
    dependencies {
        runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.6.2'
        runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-terracotta:2.6.2'
        runtime 'org.terracotta:terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime:5.2.0'
    }
```

That will enable automatic download of other necessary jars from the repo and classpath setup.

And, if you setup a open source terracotta server like I did, the enterprise edition foo/lib/ehcache-terracotta-ee-2.6.2.jar will cause an error:

> ERROR - An Enterprise client can not connect to an Opensource Server,
>   Connection refused.

**The key part:**

Run the app with `grails -noreloading run-app` instead of `grails run-app` to bypass the reloading agent. Then the distributed cache app should be working.

p.s. Deploying the app to production requires no extra work.

Comment: actually -noreloading did the trick. I've kept jars in lib (without runtime maven deps) and it works. Thank you man.

Comment: Do you guys know why this works? (It does for me as well.) However, I would like to have distributed caching enabled in a dev environment where I would also like to have auto-reloading. The error message (jar missing in classpath) leaves me with hope to solve this differently!

Comment: Maybe you can try to raise a jira for that?